Beautiful clocks using bxcoloremoji package
This is a follow-up of the question A grid in a cartesian plane of clocks using clock package
Starting from the answer of @Ignasi:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{clock}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
        
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,...,10}{
    \foreach \j 
    [evaluate=\j as \h using {int(12*rnd)}, 
    evaluate=\j as \m using {int(60*rnd)}]
    in {1,...,10} 
        \node at (\i,\j) {\clock{\h}{\m}};}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

is it possible to have the clocks using this recent package bxcoloremoji (v1.0a [2024/11/18])?


please don't link to particular mirrors. you should only link to the round robin thing which redirects to mirrors. pretty sure Illinois isn't my closest mirror ....

that said, the package depends on twmojis according to the summary, but a search of ctan returns no results.

As far as I know, Unicode only has the times on the full hour encoded as emojis. So, altough there might be a font that provides such glyphs, you can't use any emoji font for that. The font provided via the twemojis packages seems to have half hours as well, but that's about it. Not every possible clock face exists as predefined glyph in the font if I understand this correctly.

The twemojis package just inputs images of the emojis using a huge PDF that contains all glyphs. It should be possible to extract the information from this PDF and create a clock face that resembles that of the emoji font, or you could first calculate the angle distance from the two hands and rotate the relevant full-hour emoji accordingly.

@cfr I have not understood. Excuse me.

@JasperHabicht Thank you very much for your comment. Hence is not possibile to realize my question? Regards.

@JasperHabicht just ignore me ;). I didn't look carefully enough. I've deleted my comment. twmojis appears to be a typo in the summary submitted by the package author.

Well, you could just draw it with TikZ, you just need to find the right colors and dimensions.
Here, I'm using the circle shape and add a before background path, or two actually, on-the-fly. The circle/fbg key is setup so that the origin is at the circle's center and \innerradius is the distance between that origin and the inner border of the border.
The solution below uses hard-coded, but font dimensions, so they scale with the current text but they could be made more dependent on each other (line width of the circle, line width of the hands, length of the hands, size of the circle).

The calculation for the hour hand uses the value of the minutes as 3:15 is not the same as 12:00 rotated.
Code
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd} % for axis_height
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  set fbg/.code=\tikz@addoption{\pgfutil@namedef{pgf@sh@fbg@\tikz@shape}{#1}},
  circle/fbg/.style={% beFore BackGround
    shape=circle, set fbg={\pgftransformshift{\centerpoint}\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\innerradius{\radius-max(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep})-.5\pgflinewidth}#1}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  clock/on baseline/.style={baseline=default},
  clock/on center/.style={baseline=-axis_height},
  clock/every picture/.style={clock/on baseline},
  clock/every hand/.style={line cap=round, draw=cyan!50!black, line width=+.1ex},
  clock/hand length/.code=\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\clockhandlength{#1},
  clock/hour/.style={clock/every hand, clock/hand length=\innerradius-.4ex},
  clock/minute/.style={clock/every hand, clock/hand length=\innerradius-.2ex},
  clock/.style args={#1:#2}{
    line width=+.15ex, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+1.75ex,
    draw=cyan!70!black, fill=cyan!10!gray!50,
    circle/fbg={
      \draw[clock/hour]   (0,0) -- ({90-(#1)*30-(#2)/2}:\clockhandlength);
      \draw[clock/minute] (0,0) -- ({90-(#2)*6}:\clockhandlength);}}}
\newcommand*\tikzclock[2][]{\tikz[clock/every picture,#1]\node[clock=#2]{};}
\begin{document}
{\tikzset{clock/every picture/.append style=clock/on center}
 \tikzclock{1:00}\foreach \i in {2, ..., 12}{${}\to{}$\tikzclock{\i:00}}}
\par\medskip
\foreach \h in {0, ..., 3}
  \foreach \m in {0, 5, ..., 59}{%
  \h:\ifnum\m<10 0\fi\m~\tikzclock{\h:\m} \quad}\\\null
\par\medskip
\tikz[x=6mm, y=6mm]\LARGE
  \foreach \i in {1,...,10}
    \foreach \j[evaluate={\h=int(12*rnd); \m=int(60*rnd);}] in {1,...,10} 
      \node[clock=\h:\m] at (\i,\j) {};
\end{document}

Output


+1, but too straight-forward for my taste =3

I want to sincerely thank you for the incredible work you've done. Truly, it's an amazing piece of work, just like @JasperHabicht. At the moment, I'm not sure which one to choose. Both are beautiful works, and I don't want to pick just one. Unfortunately, I don't have enough points available to vote at the moment. I'll wait until 1 AM to cast my vote. Thank you so much again!

Done! I have voted you.

The glyphs you show are those from the twemojis package. But regardless of this fact, Unicode only encodes emoji glyphs for full and half hours. So, all other clock faces need to be created in some other way.
One idea could be to calculate the difference between the hour and the minute hand for all possible faces (reduced to five-minute steps) and rotate the relevant glyph accordingly.
For example like this (positioning of the ouput might need some adjustment when used inline):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3draw, twemojis}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_new:N \l_sebastiano_emoji_clockface_angle_diff_fp
\coffin_new:N \l_sebastiano_emoji_clockface_coffin
\NewDocumentCommand { \clockface } { m m } {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_sebastiano_emoji_clockface_angle_diff_fp {
        #1 - floor( #1 / 12 ) * 12 -
        ceil( ( #2 - floor( #2 / 60 ) * 60 ) / 5 ) 
    }
    
    \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_sebastiano_emoji_clockface_coffin { 
        \fp_compare:nNnTF { 
            \l_sebastiano_emoji_clockface_angle_diff_fp
        } = { 0 } {
            \twemoji { 1f55b }
        } { 
            \twemoji { \int_to_hex:n { 
                \fp_eval:n { 
                    128335 + 
                    \l_sebastiano_emoji_clockface_angle_diff_fp +
                    ( \l_sebastiano_emoji_clockface_angle_diff_fp < 0 ? 12 : 0 )
                } 
            } } 
        }
    }

    \draw_begin:
        \draw_transform_rotate:n { 
            ceil( ( #2 - floor( #2 / 60 ) * 60 ) / 5 ) * -30
        }
        \draw_coffin_use:Nnn \l_sebastiano_emoji_clockface_coffin { vc } { hc }
    \draw_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}\centering
    
    \clockface{9}{00}

    \clockface{15}{15}

    \clockface{9}{50}

\end{document}


Maybe the calculation can be streamlined. I only stitched together some ideas here.

Spectacular. An immense job! Thank you for contributing, truly thank you.

Needs optimization for sure. Ideas welcome!

Fantastic suggestion, hats off
